# Problem using Flutter Provider when updating a value during build

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to update my uid in a provider just after checking whether a user is logged. When I do that, throws an error when building widgets even though the app does not crash. Here is the code:

```
class HandleAuth extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var user = Provider.of<FirebaseUser>(context);
    if (user != null) {
      print('user.uid is ${user.uid}');
      final loggedUserInfo = Provider.of<LoggedUserInfo>(context, listen: false);
      loggedUserInfo.updateUserInfo(user.uid);
      print('first scan screen user: ${loggedUserInfo.userUid}');

    }
    return (user == null)
            ? WelcomeNewUserScreen()
            : ServicesAroundMe();
  }
}
```

And here is the provider:

```
class LoggedUserInfo with ChangeNotifier {
  String _uid;

  String get userUid {
    return _uid;
  }

  void updateUserInfo(String updatedUid) {
    _uid = updatedUid;
    print('updated uid is $_uid');
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

It throws this error:

> This ListenableProvider widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
>   The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was: ListenableProvider

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to bear in mind that each time you call the method updateUserInfo, the notifyListeners() is triggered which tries to rebuild dirty widgets. `Provider.of<T>(context)` without the argument `listen: false` also does the same thing. Hence 2 rebuild trigger are called which cause the error.

When working with a provider, it is advisable to use a stream.

To make your code more scalable, create a custom class for your user and either use ChangeNotifier or provider and streams.

For example:

```
class User {
  final String uid;
  final String displayName;
  User({ @required this.uid, this.displayName });
}

class Auth {
 
   User _firebaseUserMapper( FirebaseUser user) {
       if(user == null){
           return null;
       }
       return User(uid: user.uid, displayName: user.displayName);
   }

   Stream<User> get onAuthStateChange {
       return Firebase.instance.onAuthStateChanged.map(_firebaseUserMapper);
   }
   

}
```

In your page screen, you use like below

```
class HandleAuth extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final auth = Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false);
    return StreamBuilder<User>(
         stream: auth.onAuthStateChanged,
         builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
             if( snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
                   User user = snapshot.data;
                   if (user == null ){
                       return WelcomeNewUserScreen();
                   }
                   return Provider<User>.value(
                        value: user,
                        child: ServicesAroundMe(),
                   );
              }
              return Scaffold(
                  body: Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator();
                  ),
              );
         }
    );
}
```

The stream will forever listen for a currentUser/newUser and navigate to the appropriate page.

Comment: Hello @Loic, thanks a lot for your quick answer. I'm new to Flutter so I need some time to figure that out. Since you use Provider.of<Auth> I understand I need to declare a ChangeNotifierProvider in MyApp and then Add the mixin to the Auth class?

Comment: Also from what I understood using the argument listen: false should avoid rebuilding the widget, so I don't understand why it rebuilds in my code when I call the updateUserInfo.

Comment: There is no need to call notifyListener() when the update doesn't affect the UI in realtime.  So you don't need to call notifyListener() in `updateUserInfo()` since Provider.of<FirebaseUser>(context) with update the state (Firebase is also a state manager). 

In short to fix your code, either add `listen:false` to Provider.of<FirebaseUser>(context)  or remove notifyListener() ;

Comment: Ok thanks. I thought that adding listen: false to only the loggedUserInfo provider was enough, I didn't know that all providers were rebuilt once notify listeners was called. I tested your solution, it works, thats. Tried to upvote but I'm new, not enough reputation :(

Comment: You are welcome. I will appreciate if you can accept the answer as a correct one.